# Customise Microsoft web chat

Tags: botframework, bots, web-chat

I am trying to customize Microsoft web chat with React project:

- npm install botframework-webchat@master

In the previous version I have customized web UI by forking the master, but at this time I don't want to lose updates in master, here is the reference I have followed [Microsoft Bot Webchat](http://%20https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).

I am trying to edit user/bot icons with respective images and I don't need upload button shown below

[image]

tried to create middleware, and a custom component which extends actual component but no luck, I am not sure it is possible with the latest master. Please guide me how we can do.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got with styling:

```
import { createStyleSet } from 'botframework-webchat;

const styleSet = createStyleSet({});

styleSet.uploadButton = { ...styleSet.uploadButton,
  display: 'none'
};

styleSet.avatar = {...styleSet.avatar,
  backgroundImage: `url(${imageUrl})`
};
```

while returning send properties to the component as

```
botAvatarInitials= ' '
userAvatarInitials= ' '
styleSet={styleSet}`
```